# Crontab not meeting all requirements

Tags: linux, cron

Here is my crontab entry which I basically want to run on April 1st of every year, but only if April 1st lands on a Thursday.

```
0 13 1 4 4 /path/to/my/script.sh
```

But this seems to be running every week. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem of the crontab entry is [already pointed out](/a/645282/72456), but to execute your script as your expected date&time, change your job schedule to:

```
0 13 1 4 * [ "$(date +\%u)" -eq 4 ] && /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

`man -s 5 crontab` says:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields
> — day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (i.e.,
> aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the
> current time.

Your specification for the day is both `1st day` and `Thursday`, so it runs on both (but not twice if the 1st is also a Thurday, as in 2021).

The usual work-around is to have the crontab run on the 1st, and have the script check the day of week using `date` command, and exit early unless Thursday.

This seems a lot of trouble for a script that only runs every seven years.

Comment: what about leap years?

Comment: @Seamus  On average over the long run (over 400 years), a specific day number will fall on each of the seven days equally. 1st April advances by one day usually, two days of the week every fourth year, but then it will skip right over the Thursday once in 28 years to compensate (e.g. 1987-88 and 2015-16). 7 does not exactly divide into 365 or 366 -- it just happens to run a more complex cycle due to leap years: 6, 5, 6, 11 (until a century year intervenes). Try `for yy in {2000..2199}; do date -d $yy-04-01 "+$yy %A"; done | grep "Thurs"`.

Comment: Yes - impressive analysis. I was only commenting on the last sentence in your answer - I only meant that due to the leap year, it won't *always* run every seven years. But on average - yes. The script is nice, too, but reaches the end of its 32-bit rope in 2032. Time is fascinating; time-keeping even more so. Perhaps your closing could have been, "... a lot of trouble for a script that will only run twice through the end of the 32-bit epoch" ??  :)

Comment: @Seamus  I worked through Y2K, but even if I make it to Y_MaxInt, I probably won't know -- I will be a senile 88 by then. My days are numbered -- just not very sensibly.

Comment: Not that far behind, Paul :)  Thanks, I learned something here.

Comment: @Seamus  I believe Linux `cron` and `at` (seem to be the same daemon) have been fixed. I can schedule a job `at now + 5000 years`, and atq reports 7021 AD. I will update this comment in due course.

Comment: That's interesting. Here's my guess: `cron` & `at` are simply ignoring the `time_t` issue - just as we do when we discuss a future date. iow, they don't store their time values in the same data type as `time_t`. `time_t` will always have limits - a lower and an upper bound... why tie yourself to that if you don't need to?

Comment: I have tracked through to /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h via time_t >__time_t > __TIME_T_TYPE > __SYSCALL_SLONG_TYPE >__SQUAD_T > long int, and confirmed in C that sizeof(time_t) is 8 and the current value prints with format %ld, no warnings. Also, used date -d offset -2 ^ 33 > 1697AD, and +2 ^ 33 > 2242AD. I'm convinced the whole 32-bit time issue has gone away in Linux, even on 32-bit systems (which resolves it to __quad_t).

Comment: Bravo! That sounds like the answer to a question that hasn't been asked yet :)  I wonder why we've not heard more of it? Perhaps it's no longer a problem on Linux systems w/64-bit processors, but [remains an issue for many embedded systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)?